# Ghidra not loading classes and types of external library

Tags: ghidra, libraries, mach-o, macos

I'm analyzing a mac OS framework, and while redefining types in the decompilation view,
I wish to define one of the types as a type defined as `NSData` class which is defined inside `CoureFoundation` framework that is in the Imports tree:

[image]

I've added this frameworks as a program to the project, analyzed it, and set it as external program in the imports tree for my first framework:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now after doing all this I still cannot use the classes and types defined from `CoreFoundation` or any other external library. I even tried to run `FixupELFExternalSymbolsScript.java` plugin but it only works for ELF and not Mach-O.

What can I do for my first framework which depends on the types and classes defined in other frameworks to be able to access them so I could use them in the decompiler view?

If it matters I'm analyzing these macOS frameworks on a Windows host.